# Conjonction ni ... ni: if one subject is plural and one is singular, which must the verb agree with in number?

Tags: verbes, accord, conjonctions

> Neither the reader nor the characters receive(s) an answer to this question.

Je veux le traduire en français mais je ne sais pas comment faire l'accord, puisque le sujet *the reader* est au singulier, mais *the characters* est au pluriel.

En anglais, je dirais qu'en générale on fait l'accord avec le deuxième sujet (puisque c'est plus naturel ; je ne sais pas s'il y a une règle). Voici ce que je dirais si je parlais avec un ami :

> Neither the reader nor the characters receive an answer
>
> Neither the characters nor the reader receives an answer

... mais, en fait, je ne suis pas assez sure, même en anglais, pour l'écrire dans une dissertation. Mes tentatives en français :

> Ni le lecteur ni les personnages ne reçoivent une réponse à cette question
>
> Ni les personnages ni le lecteur ne reçoit une réponse à cette question

Si quelqu'un peut m'expliquer la règle, je serai vraiment reconnaissante.

Merci !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En français, le pluriel l'emporte sur le singulier, il faut donc mettre le verbe au pluriel.
Et sachant que les deux parties ne ne recevront pas la réponse, si "personnage" était au singulier, il y aurait quand même accord : ni le lecteur ni le personnage ne recevront la réponse.
L'accord au singulier se fait si l'action du verbe ne concerne qu'une personne : il n'y aura qu'un vainqueur, ni l'un ni l'autre ne gagnera.

Answer (score 2):

On a deux raisons de mettre le verbe au pluriel dans cette phrase :

- les deux sujets s'ajoutent,
- l'un des deux sujets est au pluriel.

Mais il pourrait y avoir des cas où on pourrait avoir un verbe au singulier avec des sujets coordonnés par *ni*.

Voir :

- [Sujets unis par ni](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1490) sur la BDL.
- [Logilangue](http://www.logilangue.com/public/Site/clicGrammaire/NiNi_AccordVerb.php)